# Converting numpy solution into dask (numpy indexing doesn't work in dask)

Tags: python, numpy, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to convert my monte carlo simulation from `numpy` into `dask`, because sometimes the arrays are too large, and can't fit into the memory. Therefore I set up a cluster of computers in the cloud: My dask cluster consists of 24 cores and 94 GB of memory. I prepared a simplified version of my code for this question.

**My original `numpy` code looks like this:**

```
def numpy_way(sim_count, sim_days, hist_days):
   historical_data = np.random.normal(111.51, 10, hist_days)
   historical_multidim = np.empty(shape=(1, 1, sim_count, hist_days))
   historical_multidim[:, :, :, :] = historical_data


   random_days_panel = np.random.randint(low=1,
                                      high=hist_days,
                                      size=(1, 1, sim_count, sim_days))
   future_panel = historical_multidim[np.arange(1)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis],
                                      np.arange(1)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis],
                                      np.arange(sim_count)[:, np.newaxis],
                                      random_days_panel]
   return future_panel.shape
```

> Note: I'm just returning here the shape of the numpy array (but as it is numpy the elements of future_panel are cumputed in memory.

Some words about the function:

- I'm creating a random array `historical_data` - this is only 1D
- Then this array is 'broadcasted' to a 4D array (`historical_multidim`). First two dimensions are not used here (but they are in my final application)

  - 3rd dimension represents how many simulations are done
  - 4th dimension is the number of days `forecasted` in the future
- `random_days_panel` - is just an `ndarray` of randomly chosen days. So the final `shape` of this array is: 1, 1, sim_count, sim_days (explained in the previous point)
- `future_panel` is an `ndarray` with the randomly picked values from `historical_multidim`. I.e. an array generated from historical data having the expected shape (1, 1, sim_count, sim_days)

Now, the problem is, that some of these steps are not implemented in dask:

- `historical_multidim[:, :, :, :] = historical_data` - `stack` or
  `broadcast_to` is recommended to use
- the slicing used in `future_panel` is not possible in dask

So I came out with this solution:

```
def dask_way_1d(sim_count, sim_days, hist_days):
    historical_data = da.random.normal(111.51, 10, size=hist_days, chunks='auto')
    def get_random_days_1d():
        return np.random.randint(low=1, high=HIST_DAYS, size=sim_days)
    future_simulations = [historical_data[get_random_days_1d()] for _ in range(sim_count)]
    future_panel =  da.stack(future_simulations)
    future_panel = da.broadcast_to(future_panel, shape=(1, 1, sim_count, sim_days))
    future_panel.compute()
    return future_panel.shape
```

This solution works, however it is much much slower than the numpy solution. The problem is, that `get_random_days_1d()` returns a `numpy` array. I tried to use `dask` array, but get into an error when computing `historical_data[get_random_days_1d()]` -> `KilledWorker: ("('normal-932553ab53ba4c7e908d61724430bbb2', 0)", ...`

Another solution looks like this:

```
def dask_way_nd(sim_count, sim_days, hist_days):
    historical_data_1d = da.random.normal(111.51, 10, size=hist_days, chunks='auto')
    historical_data_2d = da.broadcast_to(historical_data_1d, shape=(sim_count, hist_days))
    random_days_panel = np.random.randint(low=1,
                                          high=hist_days,
                                          size=(sim_count, sim_days))
    future_panel = historical_data_2d[np.arange(sim_count)[:, np.newaxis], random_days_panel]
    future_panel = da.broadcast_to(future_panel, shape=(1, 1, sim_count, sim_days))
    future_panel.compute()
    return future_panel.shape
```

This solution stops on `future_panel = historical_data_2d[np.arange(sim_count)[:, np.newaxis], random_days_panel]` -> The error is: `NotImplementedError: Don't yet support nd fancy indexing`

So my question is, Is there any way to implement the same behavior as in my numpy code? But of course I want achhieve better performance (i.e. faster execution time)

Comment: have you had a look at the [multiprocessing library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)?

Comment: Yes, of course. Actually, I am investigating what are the possible solutions to parallelize my current solution. The problem is that sometimes I have too large datasets which can't fit into memory on a single computer, so I wanted try out some solution with distributed computing

Comment: I had similar issues with an incomplete `pandas.Dataframe` API. I had to reimplement my problem  in a map-reduce way, dask offers such functionality like `scatter`, `map` and `gather`. Could you call your function for every value in  `hist_days` or one of the other arguments ?

Comment: FWIW I find that questions that focus on how to use a particular feature are much more commonly answered than questions of the form "here is my full workflow, please help"

Comment: @rocksportrocker Sorry, I need some time to return back to this topic. But basically what you are suggesting is to split the data into smaller chunks - `scatter` it to the distributed memory - do the calculation there, and `gather` the results? I need to dig deeper into dask

Comment: @MRocklin Do you think it would be a good idea to create another question focusing only on the main problem here?

Comment: @patex1987 yes, this worked for me within a small experiment trying to move something from an existing HPC batch system based analysis to dask.

Comment: Now, this might not answer your question, but it looks to me, you can change your code to a more memory efficient solution. 
def my_numpy_way(sim_count, sim_days, hist_days):
  historical_data = np.random.normal(111.51, 10, size=hist_days).astype(np.float32)
  future_panel = historical_data[..., np.random.randint(low=1, high=hist_days, size=(1, 1, sim_count, sim_days)).astype(np.int32)]
  return future_panel.shape

Answer (score 1):

Chunk `random_days_panel` instead of `historical_data` and use [`da.map_blocks`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.array.map_blocks.html):

```py
def dask_way(sim_count, sim_days, hist_days):
    # shared historical data
    # on a cluster you'd load this on each worker, e.g. from a NPZ file
    historical_data = np.random.normal(111.51, 10, size=hist_days)

    random_days_panel = da.random.randint(
        1, hist_days, size=(1, 1, sim_count, sim_days)
    )
    future_panel = da.map_blocks(
        lambda chunk: historical_data[chunk], random_days_panel, dtype=float
    )

    future_panel.compute()

    return future_panel
```

This will delegate all the work to the workers and will become faster than pure numpy once your problem gets large enough to amortize the initial (constant) cost for bringing up the scheduler and distributing the context:

```
hist_days = int(1e6)
sim_days = int(1e5)
sim_count = int(1000)

# dask_way(sim_count, sim_days, hist_days)
# (code in this answer)
532 ms ± 53.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# numpy_way(sim_count, sim_days, hist_days)
# (code in the question)
4.47 s ± 79.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# dask_way_1d(sim_count, sim_days, hist_days)
# (code in the question)
5.76 s ± 91.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```